# Is there a way to make my word counting program faster without using impure tricks?

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, immutability

As a little exercise, I made the following word counting program in haskell. It counts distinct words in a text file, and outputs the 50 most frequent ones along with their frequencies.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

-- Count words
count = Map.toList . foldl' increment Map.empty
    where
        increment dict k = Map.insert k (1 + Map.findWithDefault 0 k dict) dict

-- Sort the counts
countAndSort = sortBy (flip $ comparing snd) . count

-- Pretty printing
pp :: Show a => [(String,a)] -> IO()
pp = putStrLn . foldl' format "" where
    format text (x,y) = text ++ "\n" ++ x ++ "\t" ++ show y

main = readFile  "pg13951.txt" >>= pp . take 50 .countAndSort . splitOn " "
```

The problem is that it's that it's 16 times slower than my python implementation with a mutable dict:

```
def increment(dic,word):
    dic[word] = dic.get(word,0) + 1
    return dic

print sorted(reduce(increment,open("pg13951.txt").read().split(),{}).items(),key=lambda e:-e[1])[:50]
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that ghc is constanstly realocating new maps when it could reuse the same one over and over. Run-time statitistics show a lot of allocations:

```
$ ghc -rtsopts count.hs
$ ./count +RTS -sstderr

de      7682
et      4423
la      4238
<snip>
d'Artagnan      511
M.      502
c'est   443
d'Artagnan,     443

     705,888,048 bytes allocated in the heap
     655,511,720 bytes copied during GC
     139,823,800 bytes maximum residency (10 sample(s))
       1,049,416 bytes maximum slop
             287 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1366 colls,     0 par    2.16s    2.26s     0.0017s    0.0072s
  Gen  1        10 colls,     0 par    2.86s    3.09s     0.3093s    1.5055s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    3.18s  (  3.36s elapsed)
  GC      time    5.02s  (  5.36s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time    8.20s  (  8.72s elapsed)

  %GC     time      61.2%  (61.4% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    221,831,366 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  38.8% of total user, 36.5% of total elapsed
```

My question is: is there a way to make this program perform better, without resorting to dirty tricks such as working in the IO monad, using mutable data structures, etc. ?

PS: the data file is available at the following URL: http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/13951/pg13951.txt

Comment: How does it perform if you use Data.Map.Strict?  If you look at the source for Data.Map, you'll see the default implementation is Data.Map.Lazy and that you should use Data.Map.Strict if "You will eventually need all the values stored" and "The stored values don't represent large virtual data structures to be lazily computed".  Seems to me that describes your case exactly.

Comment: @itsbruce : I tried it, but it didn't change much. As per @shang's answer, I think the biggest issue was using `String` instead of `Data.Text`. I'll test more tonight.

Comment: you could also parallelise the code, wordcount is a typical example for a mapReduce-style computation; you can also try compiling with `-threaded` and running with `+RTS -N<nCores>` to use more cores on your machine

Comment: @jev : yeah, of course, but that's not the point of the question :)

Comment: at least the threaded setup you get more or less for free and i woulnd't consider it an impure trick

Comment: Maybe pedantic, but there's nothing "impure" about the IO monad or mutable structures in ST; that's the point. What did you learn (or were confused by) from time and space profiling your code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are some quick and simple optimizations that I tried.

Original version on my machine:

```
real    0m1.539s
user    0m1.452s
sys 0m0.076s
```

1. Instead of using `insert` and `foldl'` you can use `fromListWith` to count
   the words.

   ```
   count = Map.toList . Map.fromListWith (+) . flip zip (repeat 1)
   ```

   This is over twice as fast.

   ```
   real    0m0.687s
   user    0m0.648s
   sys 0m0.032s
   ```
2. The `String` type is a linked list of characters which makes manipulating
   strings rather elegant but inefficient. We can use the `Text` type to get more
   efficient string handling. I also rewrote your `pp` function to use `unlines`
   instead of `foldl'` and use `words` instead `splitOn` for the original split.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

   import Data.Monoid
   import Data.Text (Text)
   import qualified Data.Text as T
   import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

   pp :: Show a => [(Text,a)] -> IO()
   pp = T.putStrLn . T.unlines . map format where
       format (x,y) = x <> "\t" <> (T.pack $ show y)

   main = T.readFile  "pg13951.txt" >>= pp . take 50 .countAndSort . T.words
   ```

   Again, twice as fast as the previous step.

   ```
   real    0m0.330s
   user    0m0.316s
   sys 0m0.008s
   ```
3. Use the strict version of `Map`

   ```
   import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
   ```

   About 20% speed increase

   ```
   real    0m0.265s
   user    0m0.252s
   sys 0m0.008s
   ```

Comment: Use `alter` instead `find + insert` should be better too

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was hoping to get.

Comment: Note that `words` gives slightly different results than `splitOn " "` because it splits on all whitespace (including linefeeds). However, I think it's the desired behavior in this case.

Comment: Note that it's not `fromListWith` per se that gets you the improvement.  It's that it internally uses a better version of `increment`, that is `increment dict k = Map.insertWith (+) k 1 dict`.

Comment: You might also consider using `Data.HashMap.Strict` from `unordered-containers`, it performed better on my system.